# This code snippet in python is not executing .Can please point out the mistakes ? I am a beginner

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code snippet in python is not executing. Can someone please point out the mistakes?

```
print("Lets have a math quiz")
def True_False(x):
    if True :
        print("You are absolutely correct")
    else :
        print("Sorry you are wrong better luck next time ")

i =input("what is 4 * 4 = ")
if i == "16":
    True_False(True)
else:
    True_False(False)

i =input("what is 7+ 60 = ")
if i == "76":
    True_False(True)
else:
    True_False(False)

i =input("what is 4 * 0 = ")
if i == "0":
    True_False(True)
else:
    True_False(False)
```

Comment: Format this as code, please. You'll want to put 4 blanks at the start of each line. Also, please show the actual output, and the expected output. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `if True` will always take that branch. You want `if x`.

Comment: Suggestion to restructure: `def func(i, solution): if i == solution: print("Correct")` etc.

Comment: Note that generally speaking, "please point out the mistakes in this code" (without any further detail about the precise misbehavior) is not a class of question we welcome -- we ask that your question be about a *specific* problem, and that you do the work of isolating that problem (with the shortest possible code that reproduces it) *before* asking questions here.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is with the `True_False` function. `if True: ...` will always take the `if` branch and never the `else` branch, without checking the `x` argument at all.

You need to change the `if` statement so that it depends on the argument, and you should probably give the function and argument more descriptive names while you're at it:

```
def give_feedback(correct):
    if correct:
        print("You are absolutely correct")
    else:
        print("Sorry you are wrong better luck next time")
```

Secondly, when you call this function in the main program, your `if i == ...` checks are redundant. If `i` is `16`, then `i == 16` will evaluate to `True`, so you can simply pass that to the function:

```
guess = input("what is 4 * 4 = ")
give_feedback(guess == "16")
```

Alternatively, you could refactor the function so that it takes the user's guess and the correct answer, and performs the check itself:

```
def check_guess(guess, answer):
    if guess == answer:
        print("You are absolutely correct")
    else:
        print("Sorry you are wrong better luck next time")

guess = input("what is 4 * 4 = ")
check_guess(guess, "16")
```